# ImageView in LinearLayout give a fixed width in percent

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter

I'm using a ListView, for each item I created an imageview + an edittext. I load images from a website and I don't understand why some images have not a width of 35%. However I use the layout_weight property. Can you tell me how to force the image to take 35% of the width ?

For example, the result i have now :

[image]

And here is my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:contentDescription="42"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:text="Title"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you see what is wrong :/

Best regards,
Zed13

Edit : The result with Rishi Paul solution

[image]

And the updated xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:contentDescription="42"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:text="Title"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set parameter you want to suppress to `0dp` either its `width` or `height`

Comment: make sure your images are of same size, or you resize them after downloaded.

Comment: If I can't succeed to scale the images with the xml part I will resize the images.

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/ chk adapter downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do Like This. It Will Help You

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/poster"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="42"
    android:src="@drawable/desert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.65"
    android:text="Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of that layout you can use This @zed13

Comment: Not, totally, It's better but I still have undesirable images. I tried to use fitCenter, to force the image to fill the width but no result too. I edited the first post to show you the result.

Comment: Have you replaced with this layout?\

Comment: Which layout ? You didn't give any link :/

Comment: Have You replaced Your Xml with the code i Posted? Can You show me the updated Xml?

Comment: Replace all Your XML with this Xml.

Comment: I still have the same issue with your xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81956/discussion-between-rishi-paul-and-zed13).